# How can you find relations in tables that don't have constraints for these relations?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with a lot of tables (644) and none of them have "system" relations or constraints, they have relations because the values match each other. When they created the table, they never set the constraints or relation. I cannot even get the ERD model because there's no "system" relation between the tables, only matching values relation.

The problem is that some tables have relation because they have the same value but the names of columns don't have any similar names to understand the relations.

For example there's a column named `table1.laborcode` and it has relation with `table2.personid`.

I thought that there might be a SQL query or code that you can execute and find all matching values between all tables.

For example, here I only know that these two tables has the relation with matching values:

```
table1.laborcode = 123
table2.personid = 123
```

If you have any questions about this issue: you can ask me and I'll answer it.

Comment: Join the tables on matching columns.

Comment: To be clear, I assume that you're saying that the database has no foreign keys between tables, that you've ran `select * from sys.foreign_keys` to be sure. Can you also look with `select * from sys.extended_properties ep
join sys.objects o on ep.major_id = o.object_id` to see if that helps you any? (It probably won't if no one bothered even with FKs.

Comment: I have also been working with a large DB with very few relationships. I found that a lot of the 'relationships' are maintained by stored procs and triggers. Have a look through them and see if it helps. Other than that, request a data dictionary from the vendor, or manually build one up by testing like fields. It's not a fun thing to do, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

- Are there existing applications that maintain the data?
- Are there existing reporting systems that query the data?
- Are there users with ad-hoc queries?
- Is there an expert user / maintainer you can ask.

Reverse engineering any / all of these might be your best option.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this will require a lot of manual work. You will have to build your own ERD. Perhaps you can use a query like this to find which columns are worth checking:

```
select table1, c1.name as name1, table2, c2.name as name2
from (select t.name as table1, c.* 
      from sys.columns as c
      inner join sys.tables as t
      on t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID) as c1
inner join (select t.name as table2 , c.* 
      from sys.columns as c
      inner join sys.tables as t
      on t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID) as c2
on  c1.object_id <> c2.object_id
and c1.SYSTEM_TYPE_ID = c2.SYSTEM_TYPE_ID
and c1.USER_TYPE_ID = c2.USER_TYPE_ID
and c1.MAX_LENGTH = c2.MAX_LENGTH
and c1.PRECISION = c2.PRECISION
and c1.SCALE = c2.SCALE
order by 1,2,3,4;
```

Then run another query to check if the data in one column is a sub-set of the data in the other.

```
select count(*) as result
from sampleA 
where colA1 not in (
  select colB1
  from sampleB
  )
union all
select count(*) as result
from sampleB 
where colB1 not in (
  select colA1
  from sampleA
  )
;
```

If both numbers are non-zero, it cannot be a FK, but if one or both of them are zero, it is a possibility. You would then want to check how many rows are in each table to improve your confidence.

Comment: And, another thing to check is for the value in the parent table to be unique. That would be more evidence that it is a FK for child tables. The above is all about single columns, but you also have to consider that there can be compound keys made of more than one column.